# Time series not plotting plot type

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to get a plot of fitted valves vs. residuals but am getting weird output for plot. I want points but it's only plotting numbers as the points.

```
#Air Passenger Data in R
x <- AirPassengers
y <- arima(AirPassengers, order = c(0,1,1), seasonal = c(0,1,1))
z <- fitted(y)
plot(y$residuals, z, type = 'p', ...)
```

I'm getting this:

[image: this]

Comment: Not what I get when I plot `plot(y$residuals, z, type = 'p')` - what lives in your `...` in the `plot()` is doing something you don't want to do.

Comment: Just x and y labels. Sorry didn't realized what the plot would do instead, but I want the numbers gone.

Comment: My point is that `plot(y$residuals, z, type = 'p')` looks nothing like you show in your question. It generates a neat plot of points to me, not a bunch of overlapping years. Try running the code above in a clean R session.

Comment: `fitted(y)` returns `NULL` in your example above.